# python string multiplication implementation

Tags: python, string, performance, implementation

I wonder best practice for string repetition.

I always heard I should not use `for i in range(len(x)): string += x[i]` pattern for strings joining and should use `string = ''.join(x)` instead due to inefficiency of addition operator implementation for python strings.

But speedtests are:

`$ python -m timeit "100*'string'"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.23 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "''.join(['string' for i in xrange(100)])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.45 usec per loop`

What about implementation details for string multiplication? I know that `str * n` equals `str.__imul__(n)`, but how is it implemented I don't know.

Comment: its fast ... and its good ... but theres only a handful of situations its applicable to

Comment: Check the source: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l12175

Anyways, when people say use `str.join()` rather than simple loop with `+=` they actually meant it for different strings or say a list of strings, for example if I want to join `'foo'`, `'bar'` and `'spam'` then `*` is useless here. To repeat a particular string `*` is the best way.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, thank you for link. I read method implementation and now I know that it will not use string addition several times or smth like that. They create array and memcopy string n times to that array, its fast